# Was the moon god Libulan resurrected?

Tags: resurrection

Libulan is a moon God of the Visayan pantheon. His story is roughly something like this:

> Kaptan is said to be the father of Lihangin, the god of the wind, while Magwayen sired the goddess of the sea, Lidagat.
>
> With the permission of their fathers, Lidagat and Lihangin got married and raised four kids: the strong Licalibutan who had a body made of rock; the always-happy Liadlaw (god of sun) who was covered with gold; the shy and weak Libulan (god of moon) who was made of copper; and the only daughter, Lisuga (god of stars), whose silver body always sparkled.
>
> For a time, the family seemed to be happy and had no issues at all. However, everything changed when Lihangin and Lidagat died. Their eldest son, Licalibutan, became the victim of his own greed.
>
> One day, he planned a surprise attack against the skyworld to hopefully seize its control from the supreme god Kaptan, his grandfather. Joining him were Liadlaw and Libulan who were too afraid of him to even think of backing out. Together, they went to the skyworld and blew up the gates protecting the kingdom.
>
> When Kaptan learned about the attack, he was enraged. The skygod sent three lightning bolts to his grandsons, which all melted instantly. Both Liadlaw and Libulan were reduced into a ball, while Licalibutan‘s rock-hard body broke into pieces, fell into the sea, and became what is known as land.
>
> Lisuga, unaware of what was happening, also went to the skyworld to visit his grandfather. Kaptan, too blinded by his anger, struck the innocent Lisuga with lightning as well, breaking her into thousand pieces.
>
> When he and Magwayen finally met, things started to sink in for Kaptan. He lost all his grandchildren, including the beautiful Lisuga who had nothing to do with the conspiracy at all.
>
> The grief-stricken Kaptan, upon realizing *he could no longer revive the four deities* , decided to just provide their remains with an everlasting light. Hence, Liadlaw became the sun, Libulan became the moon, and Lisuga became what we know today as the stars.

([source](https://www.filipiknow.net/the-ancient-visayan-deities-of-philippine-mythology/))

However, it is said that Malandok, the god of war, fell on love with him and that in the war that Sidapa, the god of death, and Malandok fought(to win Libulan), Sidapa won. How is that possible if Libulan was already dead?

Answer (score 0):

Libulan fell into the sea and after a while, he rose up again with 6 other moons who followed him around. That's the reason I frequently saw for the Seven Moons. I'm still looking for the version I read before, but there's quite a lot of them if you search. I'm not sure about their credibility though.